# Issue with Multi Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have used `MultiTrigger` like below

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger. Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsFocused"
               Value="True" />
    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
               Value="True" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <MultiTrigger.Setters>
    <Setter TargetName="Border"
            Property="Background"
            Value="Yellow" />
  </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
```

But the background only gets changed for `MouseOver` and not for `IsFocused`.

If I removed mouse over condition its working fine for focused event, how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate triggers:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your XAML code, the background-setting will be triggered only if both conditions are met, IsFocused AND IsMouseOver.

To trigger on each single event, do it like mm8 suggests: make two separate triggers.